# Need remote or web-based MS Access SQL tool (e.g. similar to PhpMyAdmin, but ColdFusion-based)

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion, admin

I've been looking all over the web for a ColdFusion-based SQL administration tool for Microsoft Access and I can't find one that's simple, free and allows running SQL statements. Any suggestions?

---

**Thanks for the recommends, guys, I'll try SQLSurfer. (MSSSME won't work for me.)**

"DISCLAIMER: Using MS Access in a (web based) production environment is not recommended."

I understand that, and part of my timeline for this website is to migrate the database to MySQL on our server.

My primary interest in this is to be able to fool around with SQL commands *LOCALLY* so I can modify some tables. I wouldn't use this in a production environment anyway, especially not one that already has MySQL admin (Don't worry, I have plenty of backups in case I screw something up).

Comment: You haven't explicitly said it, but I assume since you're mentioning phpMyAdmin that you want a **MySQL** tool? (If not, please clarify and I'll correct the tag change.)

Comment: Well the database is MS access, I'm assuming a MySQL tool wouldn't work with that, but I could be wrong. Basically I'm trying to get a simple way to work with SQL queries much like the Query window. The problem is I need something that will work with the built-in server on the Coldfusion Dev Edition.

Comment: Nope, it wont, which is why you should state this in the question from the start. I think Microsoft' SQL Server Studio Management Express whatever can connect remotely to MS Access databases though...

Comment: I don't think it can do design changes, though i likely can execute hand-written DDL statements. One issue is that Jet/ACE DDL is incomplete and does not include all features of Jet/ACE databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: Using MS Access in a (web based) production environment is not recommended.

That said, I have to admit that there are projects, customers, etc. where you can't get around having to deal with MS Access Databases the one or other way.

There is an Open Source project on RIAForge, called SQLSurfer which is a web-based ad-hoc query tool powered by ColdFusion. It is a simple way to execute SQL statements on your database (not restricted to MS Access). http://sqlsurfer.riaforge.org/ Actually there is no download link, but you can still get the code from SVN repo. http://svn.riaforge.org/sqlsurfer/

I have been working with an earlier version for a long time and I find it useful for executing prepared SQL statements. It is a very dangerous tool, especially in production, so I'd strictly recommend to include it in a password protected administration environment and deny public access.

Comment: I think you should qualify your first statement about Access (where you mean Jet/ACE) to limit it to web applications, where I agree that Jet/ACE is not an appropriate data store. However, it can work OK for read-only sites, or ones that are read-only for users and writable only for the admin. Michael Kaplan's old Trigeminal.com website used a Jet database behind it and used to get 100K hits a day, according to him, and it ran just fine. It was read-only, though. All that said in favor of Jet/ACE, I'd never us it in a web app myself, ever.

Comment: @David Thanks for commenting. The main purpose of the disclaimer was preventing others from pointing this out to me. If I hadn't done, someone else would have for sure. 

MS Access is a file based desktop database, and not intended or designed for high-volume, multi-user use. Its performance under such conditions frequently becomes unpredictable and unstable. Talking in terms of web based applications even Microsoft recommends that Access be used solely for development purposes and not for production (The KB article I'm referring to seems to have vanished from the website, though).

Comment: I think you mean "not...designed for high-volume multi-user use" not "high-volume, multi-user use" as it's designed from the ground up for multiple users. It may be sufficient to say "not designed for high-volume user, no matter the number of users" and I would say that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Can RDS satisfy your needs? works with CFEclipse / CFBuilder.

Comment: Neat solution IMHO. Just configure RDS for your server, add the server in CFBuilder and you're away. Dev environment only of course! Enabling RDS for live servers in not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en) - though I've not used it with MS Access, so can't guarantee it'll work.

Hopefully someone more experienced with the two can come along and give more details.

Comment: I've just looked at the history of tag editing on this, and don't see any evidence for [CF9] tag. Where are you getting that? That is, what's your point here?

Comment: Thanks for heads-up Georg. It's a pity Jeff is being stubborn on the versioned/non-synonym relations like that one, and with making communication so unnecessarily awkward.

Comment: What does this meta topic add to the quality of discussion of the orignal question?

Comment: It doesn't - that's why I was moaning. It's precisely for things like this that question-independent communication should exist on SO. Apologies to all those involved in this question for the noise caused here.

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily make one your self.**

On Adobe's website you can find at least 5 of those tutorials Here's one http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/f4cf_firstapp_part1.html which uses Apache Derby, similar to MS Access.

Of course you need to think some things through, like authentication, making some field for writting SQL statement which is going to be sent as cfquery, but it should be a nice experience to make you'r own "phpMyAdmin" ;)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL there is CFMyAdmin.com. It might connect or could be adapted to tonnect to MS Access as well.  I agree with Henry though, I'd set up the DSN for your access database, the RDS conection in CFBuilder and then use the query tool.

Other alternatives might be Lita (Mac based), or a FireFox add on like Sqlite Manager.  They may surprise you as to what they can open.

Also, Charlie Arehart has a long list of CF based SQL Query tools.  Maybe one of them could help: http://www.carehart.org/cf411/#query

Good luck